# How to extract current price in Google Sheets using importxml from

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I can't extract the price on this page with the importxml function: https://www.castorama.pl/regal-metalowy-gammel-180-x-90-x-40-cm-5-polek-175-kg-ocynk-id-69652.html

I tried to do it like below but it doesn't work.

```
=importxml(A1;"/html/body/div/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/section/div[1]/section/span[2]/text()")
```

[image: screenshot with price]

Answer (score 0):

there is no price when you disable JS so your formula does not work because google sheets importxml cant read JS elements:

[image]

Comment: Is there a chance to import the price somehow?

Comment: @Mirek if its possible then only with script this can be achieved. another alternative is to find a different website with same data

Comment: Unfortunately, the price is only on this website. Do you know how to write such a script or where to find information about it?